# How can I get host element of before selector?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery code like:

```js
$(".class::before").click(function(){
    $(this).css("display","none");
});
```

This effects on that before element. But I want to access the host element.
Please help!

Comment: Not sure to understand because `$(".class")` seems a too obvious answer...

Comment: class is my elements class name